# How to restore grub boot on a /boot partition after windows 10 booting restoration

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, windows-10, grub

I just installed `Debian testing` but it didn't put Windows 10 into grub booting options so I restored Windows 10 boot with this tutorial http://www.qliktips.com/2012/11/fix-windows-8-boot-issue.html but now I don't know how to boot on grub again. I have to add that I had to make a `/boot` partition because I encrypted my `/` partition.

So my questions are basically :

**1)** How do I set the default boot on the `/boot (hd2,4)` partition again so grub2 runs  first ? (Preferably using the GRUB Command line ?)

**2)** How do I add `Windows boot` into grub loading options so I can  boot to windows 10 from grub ?

Thanks